# How do I track down slow queries in Cloudant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have some queries running against my Cloudant service. Some of them return quickly but a small minority are slower than expected. How can I see which queries are running slowly?

Answer (score 1):

IBM Cloud activity logs can be sent to LogDNA Activity Tracker - each log item has latency measurements allowing you to identify which queries are running slower than others. For example, a typical log entry will look like this:

```
{
    "ts": "2021-11-30T22:39:58.620Z",
    "accountName": "xxxxx-yyyy-zzz-bluemix",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "httpRequest": "/yourdb/_find",
    "responseSizeBytes": 823,
    "clientIp": "169.76.71.72",
    "clientPort": 31393,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "terminationState": "----",
    "dbName": "yourdb",
    "dbRequest": "_find",
    "userAgent": "nodejs-cloudant/4.5.1 (Node.js v14.17.5)",
    "sslVersion": "TLSv1.2",
    "cipherSuite": "ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305",
    "requestClass": "query",
    "parsedQueryString": null,
    "rawQueryString": null,
    "timings": {
        "connect": 0,
        "request": 1,
        "response": 2610,
        "transfer": 0
    },
    "meta": {},
    "logSourceCRN": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloudantnosqldb:us-south:a/abc12345:afdfsdff-dfdf34-6789-87yh-abcr45566::",
    "saveServiceCopy": false
}
```

The `timings` object contains various measurements, including the response time for the query.

For compliance reasons, the actual queries are not written to the logs, so to match queries to log entries you could put a unique identifier in the query string of the request, which would appear in the `rawQueryString` parameter of the log entry.

For more information on logging see [this blog post](https://blog.cloudant.com/2019/09/16/Cloudant-Logging-with-LogDNA.html).

Another option is to simply [measure HTTP round-trip latency](https://blog.cloudant.com/2019/12/06/Timing-HTTP-Requests-in-Nodejs.html).

Once you have found your slow queries, [have a look at this post](https://blog.cloudant.com/2020/04/24/Optimising-Cloudant-Queries.html) for ideas on how to optimise queries.